# How to access specific values inside a list that are stored in a idx variable? (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I obtain by a "certain process" an index `idx` array. So now I would like to access those elements in the `a` list.
In R this is pretty straightforward, but I can't find an easy solution in python without using for-loops.

this below is the code:

```
a = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"]
idx = [2,4,7,8]

print(a[idx])  #  -->  R approach
#output should be --> "word3" "word5" "word8" "word9"
```

How can I solve this simple task? Thanks

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this?  For example, how would you code getting the *first* element of your output?

Comment: `print(*(a[i] for i in idx))`, also it does use loops, but this is impossible without them (even in R (although you don't see them there))

Comment: print([a[i] for i in idx])

Comment: @Matiis It's *not* impossible.

Comment: Look at my answer. `itemgetter` was added to the standard library over 17 years ago.

Comment: So? A loop somewhere in the internals is not the same as a `for` loop in your actual Python code.

Comment: @chepner I understand, my point was that there is a loop even tho it is internal, I just took what OP said about not using loops too literally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"]
>>> idx = [2,4,7,8]
>>> itemgetter(*idx)(a)
('word3', 'word5', 'word8', 'word9')
```

Answer (score 0):

The short and simple way is to use a list or generator comprehension and use a starred expression to unpack all of its values:

```py
a = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"]
idx = [2,4,7,8]

print(*(a[i] for i in idx))

# Output:
# word3 word5 word8 word9
```

If you wanted to replicate `R` behaviour, you can create your own custom class and alter its `__getitem__` method a bit to check whether the argument was a list or a tuple (or really any object that has `__iter__` method) and then return what `R` returns (basically using the same method as above):

```py
class List(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if hasattr(index, '__iter__'):
            return [self[i] for i in index]
        return super().__getitem__(index)


a = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8", "word9"]
b = List(a)
idx = [2, 4, 7, 8]

print(b[idx])  # add star before to print only the values without the list and stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, unfortunately I can't upvote yet